# How do i get user input with Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I'm making a Minecraft clone with Ursina engine and I want to add commands like in the real game, is there a function to get user input like `Entry()` in Tkinter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InputField.

```
input_field=InputField(y=10)
#Use input_field.text to get text from it
```

Documentation: https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#InputField